# Grammar behind using just participle in lieu of present continuous

Tags: participles

I have been reading several CV and I have found a grammatical structure that I had never seen before. I think that it consists in using just the participle instead of the present continuous, for instance:

> **Research Experience**
>
> - Undertook six-week summer placement in Centre of blah blah
> - Undertook tissue cultures of different cell lines such as EC and hES cells in
>   compliance with health and safety procedures
> - Observed several lab techniques and protocols including blah blah
> - Adhered to PPE and social distancing due to Covid-19

Is my guess correct?. What is this grammatical structure?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just simple Simple Past, with the pronoun omitted. It's common in lists such as ones in a CV to not repeat *I* / *he* / *the candidate* on every single line:

> *(The candidate)* undertook (a) six-week summer placement...
>
> *(The candidate)* undertook tissue cultures...
>
> *(The candidate)* observed several lab techniques...

Comment: (also, can I add my social distancing experience under "research"? I've been pretty good at it!)